# Swift: Around of view black

Tags: swift, crop

Hello I'm creating a function to crop the photo, I would like the outside of the container that cropping the photo is black with an opacity of 0.5, look at the picture below to better understand:

[image: All I drew in black is what I want it to be black with an opacity of 0.5, how to do this?]

All I drew in black is what I want it to be black with an opacity of 0.5, how to do this?

The user can move and change the size of frame, I use for this size change CGRect. So it is necessary that the black background is dynamic with the change of the size and the displacement of the frame, I do not know how to do it

The class of my UIIvire frame:

```
class ResizableView: UIView {

enum Edge {
    case topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight, none
}

static var edgeSize: CGFloat = 44.0
private typealias `Self` = ResizableView

var currentEdge: Edge = .none
var touchStart = CGPoint.zero

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {

        touchStart = touch.location(in: self)

        currentEdge = {
            if self.bounds.size.width - touchStart.x < Self.edgeSize && self.bounds.size.height - touchStart.y < Self.edgeSize {
                return .bottomRight
            } else if touchStart.x < Self.edgeSize && touchStart.y < Self.edgeSize {
                return .topLeft
            } else if self.bounds.size.width - touchStart.x < Self.edgeSize && touchStart.y < Self.edgeSize {
                return .topRight
            } else if touchStart.x < Self.edgeSize && self.bounds.size.height - touchStart.y < Self.edgeSize {
                return .bottomLeft
            }
            return .none
        }()
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)
        let previous = touch.previousLocation(in: self)

        let originX = self.frame.origin.x
        let originY = self.frame.origin.y
        let width = self.frame.size.width
        let height = self.frame.size.height

        let deltaWidth = currentPoint.x - previous.x
        let deltaHeight = currentPoint.y - previous.y

        switch currentEdge {
        case .topLeft:
            self.frame = CGRect(x: originX + deltaWidth, y: originY + deltaHeight, width: width - deltaWidth, height: height - deltaHeight)
        case .topRight:
            self.frame = CGRect(x: originX, y: originY + deltaHeight, width: width + deltaWidth, height: height - deltaHeight)
        case .bottomRight:
            self.frame = CGRect(x: originX, y: originY, width: currentPoint.x + deltaWidth, height: currentPoint.y + deltaWidth)
        case .bottomLeft:
            self.frame = CGRect(x: originX + deltaWidth, y: originY, width: width - deltaWidth, height: height + deltaHeight)
        default:
            // Moving
            self.center = CGPoint(x: self.center.x + currentPoint.x - touchStart.x,
                y: self.center.y + currentPoint.y - touchStart.y)
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    currentEdge = .none
}

// MARK: - Border

@IBInspectable public var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear {
    didSet {
        layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
    }
}

@IBInspectable public var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet {
        layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: You have the frame of the white rectangle? What about adding a UIView with black background color and opacity to 0.5 and you add a Mask to it to let the white rectangle visible?

Comment: The user can move and change the size of frame, I use for this size change CGRect. So it is necessary that the black background is dynamic with the change of the size and the displacement of the frame, I do not know how to do it

Comment: Please provide your code snippet for better understanding...

Comment: Update, look my code thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the [maskView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622557-maskview) to insert an image which covers the bleed area. The image should be 50% opacity in the bleed area. [Here's an example](http://arsenkin.com/ios-mask-view-with-view.html) on how to implement this technique.

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "star"))
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
view.maskView = imageView
```